# add children comments to parent comment array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

Long story short, I have to implement a `comments` view controller with nested comments (1 level) following this structure:

```
  -- Comment
     -- reply to comment 
     -- reply to comment 
  -- Comment 
  -- Comment
```

I had asked the backend if they could provide an optional  array of children comments (`let children[Comment]?`) inside so, when I delete the parent in the collection view cell, I don't have to wait for the backend to reload data, removing the object from the current data source.

Instead the Backend came up with this json where you can understand which is the parent if the `id` and the `root_comment_id` are the same. If not, all the subsequent comments belong to the first object.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "bedcab34-f6b7-44a9-ab81-6d443ada580e",
            "post_id": "03486c50-6a4a-48a3-a68e-374cf42686d8",
            "poster": {
                "id": "5b52c4ed-bd21-49fe-9439-8722e4223d50",
                "username": "foobar",
                "fullname": "foo bar",
                "avatar_url": null
            },
            "body": "Nice Post",
            "root_comment_id": "bedcab34-f6b7-44a9-ab81-6d443ada580e",
            "to_poster": null,
            "created_at": "2021-11-05T14:38:15.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "43fb2e48-2aae-4b01-bafa-456b927444d5",
            "post_id": "03486c50-6a4a-48a3-a68e-374cf42686d8",
            "poster": {
                "id": "5b52c4ed-bd21-49fe-9439-8722e4223d50",
                "username": "foobar",
                "fullname": "foo bar",
                "avatar_url": null
            },
            "body": "Yes I like it too",
            "root_comment_id": "bedcab34-f6b7-44a9-ab81-6d443ada580e",
            "to_poster": null,
            "created_at": "2021-11-05T14:38:46.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "11a4c5d6-9db8-47c1-a472-947d8d1ac81a",
            "post_id": "03486c50-6a4a-48a3-a68e-374cf42686d8",
            "poster": {
                "id": "5b52c4ed-bd21-49fe-9439-8722e4223d50",
                "username": "foobar",
                "fullname": "foo bar",
                "avatar_url": null
            },
            "body": "Awesome!",
            "root_comment_id": "bedcab34-f6b7-44a9-ab81-6d443ada580e",
            "to_poster": {
                "id": "788343e4-3695-44e5-bda4-9b0593b7a496",
                "username": "matthewzorpas",
                "fullname": "Matthew Zorpas",
                "avatar_url": null
            },
            "created_at": "2021-11-05T14:39:45.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

It doesn't really make sense to me, but since they are not gonna change it I have to map this json and make my own model which would look like this:

```
struct CommentResult: Codable {
    let result: [Comment]
    let statusCode: Int
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Comment: Codable {
    let commentID, postID: String
    let poster: Poster
    let body: String?
    let rootCommentID: String
    let toPoster: Poster?
    let createdAt: Date
    let children:[Comment]? // I would like to add this and append children with a root_id == to the parent id

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case commentID = "id"
        case postID = "post_id"
        case poster
        case body
        case rootCommentID = "root_comment_id"
        case toPoster = "to_poster"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.commentID = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .commentID)
        self.postID = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .postID)
        self.poster = try container.decode(Poster.self, forKey: .poster)
        self.toPoster = try container.decodeIfPresent(Poster.self, forKey: .toPoster)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
        let dateString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .createdAt)
        self.createdAt = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) ?? Date()
        self.body = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .body)
        self.rootCommentID = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .rootCommentID)
    }
}
```

I know I probably have to use `filter` but I have been straggling to find the proper way of doing it without increasing time complexity.

So the json would look like something this instead:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "bedcab34-f6b7-44a9-ab81-6d443ada580e",
            "post_id": "03486c50-6a4a-48a3-a68e-374cf42686d8",
            "poster": {
                "id": "5b52c4ed-bd21-49fe-9439-8722e4223d50",
                "username": "foobar",
                "fullname": "foo bar",
                "avatar_url": null
            },
            "body": "Nice Post",
            "root_comment_id": "bedcab34-f6b7-44a9-ab81-6d443ada580e",
            "to_poster": null,
            "created_at": "2021-11-05T14:38:15.000Z",
            "children": [  {
                  "id": "43fb2e48-2aae-4b01-bafa-456b927444d5",
                  "post_id": "03486c50-6a4a-48a3-a68e-374cf42686d8",
                  "poster": {
                      "id": "5b52c4ed-bd21-49fe-9439-8722e4223d50",
                      "username": "foobar",
                      "fullname": "foo bar",
                      "avatar_url": null
                  },
                  "body": "Yes I like it too",
                  "root_comment_id": "bedcab34-f6b7-44a9-ab81-6d443ada580e",
                  "to_poster": null,
                  "created_at": "2021-11-05T14:38:46.000Z"
              },
              {
                  "id": "11a4c5d6-9db8-47c1-a472-947d8d1ac81a",
                  "post_id": "03486c50-6a4a-48a3-a68e-374cf42686d8",
                  "poster": {
                      "id": "5b52c4ed-bd21-49fe-9439-8722e4223d50",
                      "username": "foobar",
                      "fullname": "foo bar",
                      "avatar_url": null
                  },
                  "body": "Awesome!",
                  "root_comment_id": "bedcab34-f6b7-44a9-ab81-6d443ada580e",
                  "to_poster": {
                      "id": "788343e4-3695-44e5-bda4-9b0593b7a496",
                      "username": "matthewzorpas",
                      "fullname": "Matthew Zorpas",
                      "avatar_url": null
                  },
                  "created_at": "2021-11-05T14:39:45.000Z"
              }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

Comment: How many levels deep can the replies go? Can replies also have replies?

Comment: hello @Rob .... luckily just one level ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have a really tough time if you try to implement a custom decoding algorithm. I'd leave the comments in tact and map the comments to a cluster of comments. In this example I've added some convenience methods and a new type called `CommentCluster`. Also note that I've shortened the `Comment` definition for the sake of brevity.

```
struct Comment: Codable {
    let commentID: String
    let postID: String
    let body: String
    let rootCommentID: String
    let createdAt: Date
}

extension Comment: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Comment, rhs: Comment) -> Bool {
        lhs.commentID == rhs.commentID
    }
}

struct CommentCluster {
    let root: Comment
    var children: [Comment]
}

extension Comment {
    var isRoot: Bool { rootCommentID == commentID }
    func isChild(of parent: Comment) -> Bool {
        rootCommentID == parent.commentID
    }
}
```

This will help with debugging:

```
extension Comment: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "\(commentID)"
    }
}
extension CommentCluster: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "root=\(root), children=\(children)"
    }
}
```

In this example I've made the assumption that the comments were decoded as is. Substitute the hardcoded comments with your decoded comments.

```
class CommentChildrenTests: XCTestCase {

    let comments: [Comment] = [
        .init(commentID: "Comment - 0", postID: "Post 0", body: "Comment - 0", rootCommentID: "Comment - 0", createdAt: .now + 0.0),
        .init(commentID: "Comment - 1", postID: "Post 0", body: "Comment - 1", rootCommentID: "Comment - 1", createdAt: .now + 1.0),
        .init(commentID: "Comment - 2", postID: "Post 0", body: "Comment - 2", rootCommentID: "Comment - 2", createdAt: .now + 2.0),
        .init(commentID: "Comment - 3", postID: "Post 0", body: "Comment - 3", rootCommentID: "Comment - 3", createdAt: .now + 3.0),

        .init(commentID: "Comment - 2-0", postID: "Post 0", body: "Comment - 2-0", rootCommentID: "Comment - 2", createdAt: .now + 4.0),
        .init(commentID: "Comment - 2-1", postID: "Post 0", body: "Comment - 2-1", rootCommentID: "Comment - 2", createdAt: .now + 5.0),
        .init(commentID: "Comment - 3-0", postID: "Post 0", body: "Comment - 3-0", rootCommentID: "Comment - 3", createdAt: .now + 6.0),
        .init(commentID: "Comment - 3-1", postID: "Post 0", body: "Comment - 3-1", rootCommentID: "Comment - 3", createdAt: .now + 7.0),
    ]

    func testIt() throws {

        let comments = comments
            .shuffled()
            .sorted(by: { lhs, rhs in
                lhs.createdAt < rhs.createdAt
            })

        let rootComments = comments
            .filter { $0.isRoot }

        let clusters = rootComments
            .map { root -> CommentCluster in
                let children = comments
                    .filter { $0 != root && $0.isChild(of: root) }
                return CommentCluster(root: root, children: children)
            }

        print("=============")
        for cluster in clusters {
            print(cluster)
        }
        print("=============")
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example I'm shuffling and sorting. You didn't mention the ordering of the comments in the JSON. So sorting may or may not be necessary for you. I just wanted to make sure that comments and replies were listed in order. That is probably important.

Also, I noticed that you were using custom CodingKeys and a DateFormatter. That is not necessary if you set the `JSONDecoder` properties properly. Check out [keyDecodingStrategy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2949119-keydecodingstrategy) and [dateDecodingStrategy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy) on `JSONDecoder`

If your team is not happy with the performance of such a solution, then push back on the backend team. They should be feeding you data in a format useful to your mobile app.

Comment: plus 1 for the Unit test. I am definitely pushing it back to the backend.

Comment: Yes, I opted for this approach. I had to make minimal changes to my implementation. Probably with many comments it won’t be perfect as far as the performance but there is nothing much I can do!

Answer (score 1):

You're right the JSON should be in a different format, but this is not always possible, this is why the DTO pattern exists.

In my solution we will use a CommentDTO object which is compliant to the Backend structure and another Comment object that describe the object used by the app.

The first step is to create the CommentDTO structure :

```
// MARK: - CommentDTO
struct CommentDTO: Codable {
    let id, postID: String
    let poster: Poster
    let body, rootCommentID: String?
    let toPoster: Poster?
    let createdAt: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case postID = "post_id"
        case poster, body
        case rootCommentID = "root_comment_id"
        case toPoster = "to_poster"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
    }
}

// MARK: - Poster
struct Poster: Codable {
    let id, username, fullname: String
    let avatarURL: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, username, fullname
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
    }
}

typealias CommentDTOS = [CommentDTO]
```

The second Step is to create the Comment structure, in this case I preferred to use 'Class' instead of 'struct' to add a direct reference to each comment Root and Children. If you use 'struct' you can just have Children reference because struct cannot have a stored property that recursively contains it.

```
class Comment {
    
    let id, postID : String
    let poster : Poster
    let body : String?
    let toPoster : Poster?
    let createdAt : String
    let rootComment : Comment?
    var childrenComments : [Comment]?
        
    init(commentDto : CommentDTO)
    {
        self.id = commentDto.id
        self.postID = commentDto.postID
        self.poster = commentDto.poster
        self.body = commentDto.body
        self.toPoster = commentDto.toPoster
        self.createdAt = commentDto.createdAt
        self.rootComment = nil
        self.childrenComments = nil
    }
    
    init(commentDto : CommentDTO, root : Comment)
    {
        self.id = commentDto.id
        self.postID = commentDto.postID
        self.poster = commentDto.poster
        self.body = commentDto.body
        self.toPoster = commentDto.toPoster
        self.createdAt = commentDto.createdAt
        self.rootComment = root
        self.childrenComments = nil
    }
    
    func addChild(comment : Comment)
    {
        if self.childrenComments == nil
        {
            self.childrenComments = []
        }
        
        self.childrenComments?.append(comment)
    }
}
```

The algorithm is really simple and use filter like you said.
Now we have an array of CommentDTO, we will select first comment that have an id equal to rootCommentID, construct a CommentObject and put it in a Map for doing some operation in O(1) time.
After we will select only element that aren't root and we will add them to our structure.

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Comments", withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                //1 : Reading data from JSON and put in an Array of CommentDTO
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let commentDTOS = try decoder.decode(CommentDTOS.self, from: data)
                
                //2 : Create a Map that contain only Comment Rootes for doing some operation in O(1)
                var commentMap : [String : Comment] = [:]
                
                //3 : Using Filter for select only roots
                let roots = commentDTOS.filter { $0.id == $0.rootCommentID }
                //4 : Create a Root Comment and put it in a Map
                roots.forEach {
                    let comment = Comment(commentDto: $0)
                    commentMap[$0.id] = comment
                }
                
                //5 : Using Filter for select only children
                let children = commentDTOS.filter { $0.id != $0.rootCommentID }
                children.forEach {
                    //6 : Retrieve root from Map
                    let root = commentMap[$0.rootCommentID!]
                    if let root = root
                    {
                        //7 : Create comment and update Root Children list
                        let comment = Comment(commentDto: $0, root: root)
                        root.addChild(comment: comment)
                    }
                }
                
                let output = Array(commentMap.values) as [Comment]
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
```

'output' is an array of Comment that contains only roots, you will access to children through their references.

Comment: Ciao Antonio... thanks a lot... I do agree with you that it's not always possible to live in a "perfect world"! ;) +1 for your detailed answer. Let me try to implement it!